# Error at tryparse decimal conversion from textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, decimal, tryparse

When i read from the XML file, i read it like this and it works,

```
decimal checkkkk = Config.Location.test.Longitude;
textBox3.Text = checkkkk.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I want to write it back to the same XML file, I'm getting a error at this point..!

```
decimal value;
Configs.Location.test.Longitude = 
decimal.TryParse(textBox3.Text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, out value);
```

What is the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method *Decimal.TryParse* returns the boolean data-type and not decimal.

> ***[Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx)***, Converts the string representation of a number to its Decimal equivalent using the specified style and culture-specific format. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed.

Try to do it this way instead:

```
decimal value;
if (decimal.TryParse(textBox3.Text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, out value)) 
{
     rseConfigs.RseLocation.GpsCoordinates.Longitude = value;
}
```